# vscode autocomplete for custom lua library

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua, autocomplete, intellisense

i am trying to figure out how to make an autocomplete plugin for vscode targeting the lua syntax described in this syntax file here:

https://github.com/danomatika/loaf/tree/master/doc/modules

i wanna be able write :

```
myFbo = of.F
```

and it should suggest

```
myFbo = of.Fbo()
```

and also be able to autocomplete on methods like:

```
myFbo:al
```

that autocompletes to

```
myFbo:allocate()
```

according to this list:

```
of.Fbo
  activateAllDrawBuffers
  allocate
  attachTexture
  beginFbo
  bind
  checkStatus
  clear
  clearColorBuffer
...
```

from here: https://github.com/danomatika/loaf/blob/master/doc/modules/of_syntax.txt

anybody got some ideas or where to ask?

ps: i have read the example on creating autocomplete plugins from vscode here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/tree/main/completions-sample
and as well browsed through the codebase of multiple lua vscode plugins but i am very lost and need a direction so here goes.